# "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

Error happens at line 1

```
<%= form_for(@premium) do |f| %>
<% if @premium.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@premium.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this 
    premium from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
```

After looking for a solution on the web there seems to be no problems with my controller or routes.
Below is part of my controller which does the deletion and the show methods without errors:

```
class PremiaController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_premium, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /premia
def index
 @premia = Premium.all
end

# GET /premia/1
 def show
end

# GET /premia/new
def new
 @premium = Premium.new
end
```

Below are my resources shown after typing "rake routes":

```
         premia GET    /premia(.:format)                   premia#index
                POST   /premia(.:format)                   premia#create
    new_premium GET    /premia/new(.:format)               premia#new
   edit_premium GET    /premia/:id/edit(.:format)          premia#edit
        premium GET    /premia/:id(.:format)               premia#show
                PATCH  /premia/:id(.:format)               premia#update
                PUT    /premia/:id(.:format)               premia#update
                DELETE /premia/:id(.:format)               premia#destroy
```

My only explanation is that is that Rails cannot connect "Premium" to its plural "Premia". I have generated a scaffold for "Premium" and the resulting controller was named "PremiaController".

I have checked my other forms and controllers within the program and they work well. What could the problem here be?

Comment: Add the error log please.

Comment: Turns out I had to restart the server.